# AWS Lambda function for resize image in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, resize

I have CMS upload image to AWS S3. First it is uploaded to my apache server and create thumbnail, after that it uploads both the original image and the thumbnail to AWS S3. It takes long time to process, I need to create function in lambda that takes any image from S3 bucket and resize it for any size I give, that's all.

I Have tried make trigger lambda with s3 work fine, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: What do you mean  by `i need to create function in lambda take any image from s3 bucket and resize it for any size i give thats all` ?

Comment: Resize image to create thumbnail

Comment: Just to make sure.. you want to create lambda function which trigger when new image added to bucket and resize the image?

Comment: No , i want function resize any image in s3 bucket to thumbnail size , i don't need to save every image size in s3 bucket , i have app and alot of screen have diffrent size

Comment: If bucket is accessible from the lambda via http, you can have a look at [nuggan](github.com/cchantep/nuggan) (I'm a contributor of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS Lambda documentation has a walkthrough that will automatically resize pictures.

See: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

The tutorial configures:

- An AWS Lambda function
- An Amazon S3 Event to trigger the Lambda function when a file is uploaded to an S3 bucket
- The Lambda function will then read the image, resize it and store it in a different S3 bucket

You can modify the code to operate differently if desired.

Comment: Mr. John, is it possible for EC2 PHP SDK to invoke lambda function and then upload to S3? I mean this workflow: local EC2 AWS PHP SDK > Lambda(Image resizing) > Upload to S3

Comment: @hiyo Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Answer (score 1):

Check below tutorial to Resize Image using Lamda function

[Resize Image using Lamda function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4iEeXlw_qU)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is a Cloudformation template provided by AWS here
https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/serverless-image-handler/

Just press launch and will deploy all needed tools and the pictures you can resize and crop how you want like 300x300/picture/path.extesnion 800x500/picture/path.extesnion

Answer (score 0):

Here is another a step-by-step [tutorial on how to resize s3 images](https://github.com/MuhammadReda/nodejs-aws-lambda-image-resizer). It walks you through how to properly configure

1. AWS Lambda (with source code to resize).
2. Amazon API Gateway.
3. Amazon S3.